# Gmail API email text cut off in Apple Mail on iPhone

Tags: python, gmail-api

I'm trying to respond to emails (that are already responses to me) using the Gmail API. It works seemingly perfectly everywhere except for Apple Mail on iPhone. It cuts off the last handful of characters and the Subject header looks incorrect

Subject header when sent from my api: `Subject: Re: =?utf-8?b?8J+TiPCfkYA=?= Are you ready?!`

Subject header when sent directly from gmail: `Subject: =?UTF-8?B?UmU6IPCfpJbwn5OIIEl0J3MgdGltZS4uLg==?=`

Code to send email:

```
def send_welcome_reply(to: str, message_id: str, message_id_header: str,
                     references_header: str, thread_id: str,
                     newsletter_str: str):
  
try:
  # Call the Gmail API
  message = EmailMessage()

  message['To'] = to
  message['From'] = 'connor@joinyellowbrick.com'
  message['In-Reply-To'] = message_id_header
  message['References'] = f"{references_header} {message_id_header}"

  # Get the email to reply to
  email = service.users().messages().get(userId='me',
                                         id=message_id).execute()

  # Get subject line
  subject = None
  headers = email['payload']['headers']
  for header in headers:
    if header['name'] == 'Subject':
      subject = header['value']

  # Set subject
  encoded_subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' + base64.b64encode(subject.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8') + '?='
  message['Subject'] = encoded_subject

  message.set_content("PLACEHOLDER")
  
  # Update labels to remove from spam, mark as read, and add to inbox
  if "id" in email and email["id"]:
    print("Marking email as read")
    body = {"removeLabelIds": ["UNREAD", "SPAM"], "addLabelIds": ["INBOX"]}

    updated_message = service.users().messages().modify(
      userId="me", id=email["id"], body=body).execute()

    if "id" not in email or not email["id"]:
      print("Error marking message as read!")

  # Send message
  encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()
  create_message = {'raw': encoded_message, 'threadId': thread_id}

  email = service.users().messages().send(userId="me",
                                          body=create_message).execute()

  print(email)

  return email
```